# Js or ES6 Get object field by path string when field has 2 or more nested levels as in myObj.one.two.three.field

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have a base object which is always the same: `project` but sometimes I have to access its fields dynamically, how can I access its fields when it can be 1 or more nested objects for example:

```
function (myPath){
  return project[myPath];

}
```

This works when using `project["oneField"]` in `myPath("oneField")`

but it does not work when it is nested to or more levels:

`myPath("one.two.fieldName")` does not work: `project["one.two.fieldName"]`

Neither like this: `project."one.two.fieldName"`

Comment: When you ask for `project["one.two.fieldName"]` you are checking if `project` has a key literally called `"one.two.fieldName"` including the dots. You can just split on dot and get an array that contains key and then traverse the object that way `obj= obj[keys[i]]`. Or other similar techniques that boil down to "split - use the results for navigating".

Comment: project["one"]["two"]["fieldName"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## option #1 (not recommended) - use the `eval` function:

```js
var projects = {
  a : {
    b : {
      c : 1
    }
  }
}
function get(myPath) {
  debugger;
  return eval("projects." + myPath)
}
console.log(get('a.b.c'))
```

## option #2 - split by `.` and go over the elements in the object:

```js
var projects = {
  a: {
    b : { 
      c : '1'
    }
  }
}

function get(path) {
  if (path.indexOf('.')) {
    subs = path.split(".")
    ret = projects;
    for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
      ret = ret[subs[i]]
    }
    return ret;
  } else {
    return projects[path];
  }
}

console.log(get('a'))
console.log(get('a.b'))
console.log(get('a.b.c'))
```

Answer (score 15):

You could do it like this (ES6):

```js
function getVal(object, path){
    return path.split('.').reduce ( (res, prop) => res[prop], object );
}

// sample data
var object = { one: { two: { fieldName: 'gotcha' } } };

// get inner field value
console.log( getVal(object, 'one.two.fieldName') );
```

You can further extend this function to also support square brackets:

```js
function getVal(object, path){
    const regex = /(?<=\[)(?!")[^\]]+|(?<=\[")[^"]+|[^."[\]]+/g;
    return path.match(regex).reduce ( (res, prop) => res[prop], object );
}

let object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
console.log( getVal(object, 'a[0].b["c"]') );
```

Comment: the best solution so far!

Comment: I really like this solution too, but this can produce an error if the nested objected doesn't exists ("cannot read prop of null"), this can be fixed with:

return myPath.split('.').reduce ( (res, prop) => res && res[prop], project );

Comment: @JollyBrackets, an error seems the right thing when referencing a property of something that is not an object. It is the same behaviour as you would do `{a: 1}.a.b.c`. But if you prefer to return `undefined` I would put the `return` in a `try` `catch` block. That has the advantage that `reduce` is really interrupted and does not perform unnecessary extra iterations, and that the `reduce` callback does not have to execute the extra test in every iteration. Note that your workaround would return 0 for `getVal({a: 0}, 'a.b.c.d')`

Comment: if you have an array inside of your object this solution does no work lets say your object is  object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] }; and path is 'a[0].b.c' then this will give out an error

Comment: @mdshoaib, but that is a syntax that is not specified in the question. You'd have to pass the path as `'a.0.b.c'`. I just added a version to my answer that covers square brackets. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if I'm doing something like this, I'll use a recursive function:

```
var data = {a: {b: {c: 5}}};

function getValue(obj, key) {
    var parts = key.split('.');
    return obj 
        && (parts.length === 1 
            && obj[key] || getValue(obj[parts[0]], parts.slice(1).join('.'))) 
    || null;
}

console.log(getValue(data, "a.b.c"));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e99rpvho/)

It's a bit concisely written, but basically if it has a key with a dot in it, it'll call it down a level. If it ever gets an `obj` that doesn't exist, it'll return null. Otherwise, once it's down to the last level, it'll return the value it found.

A more expanded, maybe easier to understand, version is:

```
function getValue(obj, key) {
    var parts = key.split('.');
    if (!obj) {
        return null;
    } else if (parts.length === 1) {
        return obj[key];
    }

    return getValue(obj[parts.slice(1).join('.')], key);
}
```